# Will Heroku be cheaper than my current VPS + Reseller setup?

Tags: heroku

Thanks to Michael Hartl's tutorial on rails, this amazing community, and twilio, I was able to learn rails and build my first app this month.

I love the the git/heroku workflow, and got thinking --

Currently I have,

~20 light PHP sites on a VPS I pay $40/month for
~10 light PHP sites + 2 Wordpress installs on a Shared Reseller Account I pay $20/month for

+1 App I just made

The PHP sites are basically static sites that have php_includes in them, to make the code a little bit less repetitive.

I'm a little confused by the Heroku pricing though, because I'm not sure how many requests constitutes one dyno, etc.

For the light PHP sites, does using Heroku make sense?

Say that all together the PHP sites get about 5000 views a month, out of which 2000 is for wordpress.

How much do you think it's going to cost me to have them up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku will answer - this is cloud and you should not think in terms of Servers or VPS but more Dynos etc. But old habits die hard :-)

For your question, very simply a Dyno has 512 MB memory (RAM), and the cost of a Dyno includes the bandwidth and the disk space you are using. There are many other issues, like Dynos being Read Only and transient, no IP assignment etc.

In your specific case, definitely use Heroku for your Rails testing, and hosting. Heroku provides hosting free for one Dyno. (Each additional Dyno - about USD 34/month)

For your static sites and PHP, why don't you use AWS with the free tier, you get your own server/vps with whole lot of other services free - http://aws.amazon.com/free/